# sql query to perform for each unique identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table like this:

```
________________________________________
phone_number  |  phone_vendor  |  status

67834         | A              | OPEN
23836         | B              | OPEN
87483         | C              | CLOSED
72377         | A              | OPEN
63637         | B              | OPEN
```

I need to find the count of phone_numbers of each unique phone_vendor in OPEN status, something like:

```
A | 2
B | 2
C | 0
```

using group by I don't get the vendors whose OPEN count is already exhausted (as C in above example)

What could be a suitable query?
Also, I can't use CASE as there will be multiple vendors.

Query attempt:

```
SELECT status, count(phone_number) AS count
FROM phone_number_table
WHERE status = 'OPEN'
GROUP BY phone_vendor, status
```

Comment: What does "OPEN count is already exhausted" mean?

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT() etc.

Comment: no OPEN count that is 0

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh SELECT  status, count(phone_number) AS count
FROM phone_number_table
WHERE status = 'OPEN' GROUP BY phone_vendor, status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count, phone_vendor  
FROM yourtable
Group by phone_vendor
```

SQL Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17e753/4

Comment: That count with case expression makes no sense. Do SUM instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for status and sum

```
  select phone_vendor, sum(case status when 'OPEN' then 1 else 0 end) my_count 
  from my_table
  group by phone_vendor
```